# Swift 3 and Alamofire: Extremely Slow Build Times

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

So, after diagnosing my code, I've narrowed it down to one line that is causing my entire project to take from seconds to hours to build. I'm passing parameters to Alamofire to send off to my API, but they cause Xcode to index/build forever. Could anyone figure out why?

Lines in question

```
        var credit_union : String = ""
        var activity : String = ""
        var task : String = ""
        var billing_options : String = ""

        var sun : Float = 0
        var mon : Float = 0
        var tue : Float = 0
        var wed : Float = 0
        var thu : Float = 0
        var fri : Float = 0
        var sat : Float = 0
        var total : Float = 0

        var sun_notes : String = ""
        var mon_notes : String = ""
        var tue_notes : String = ""
        var wed_notes : String = ""
        var thu_notes : String = ""
        var fri_notes : String = ""
        var sat_notes : String = ""

        let approval : String = ""
        let department : String = currentUser.department
        let submitted : String = "Not Submitted"
        let date_of_time : Date = startDatePassing + 1.day
        let id : Int = 0


let parameters: Parameters = [
            "credit_union": credit_union,
            "activity": activity,
            "task" : task,
            "billing_options" : billing_options,
            "sun" : sun,
            "mon" : mon,
            "tue" : tue,
            "wed" : wed,
            "thu" : thu,
            "fri" : fri,
            "sat" : sat,
            "total" : total,
            "sun_notes" : sun_notes,
            "mon_notes" : mon_notes,
            "tue_notes" : tue_notes,
            "wed_notes" : wed_notes,
            "thu_notes" : thu_notes,
            "fri_notes" : fri_notes,
            "sat_notes" : sat_notes,
            "approval" : approval,
            "department" : department,
            "submitted" : submitted,
            "date_of_time" : date_of_time
        ]
```

Comment: apparently large dict literals slow build time: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/26/swift-long-compile-time/

Comment: We have similar names :D
Is there a way to declare the parameters in a different way to avoid this?

Comment: `let parameter: Parameters`

makes the variable `parameter` an object to your class `Parameter` but you're assigning a dictionary to it.

Along with this, if today is Tuesday, do the values of other weekdays get filled as well with any useful data or just default values? Consider sending just the day's information

Comment: @EmilDavid `Parameters` is an Alamofire alias for `[String:Any]`.

Comment: Heh, yeah we do :D I don't have a source for this, but I believe I've read that it is due to type inference. Maybe split up the dict into specific types like `[String : Float]` or `[String : String]`. And then combine it. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @EmilDavid They all have useful values that get passed, I just knew it wasn't relevant to the build times so I didn't want to make y'all have to read any fluff code.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Thanks mate. Never used Alamofire before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually solve this sort of problem (I've also seen it happen with complex strings, long arrays, etc.) by building it one piece at a time.  e.g.

```
var parameters: Parameters = ["credit_union": credit_union]
parameters["activity"] = activity
// etc.
```

Comment: Wonderful! Unfortunate that this bug has been in Swift for so long, but that worked like a charm! 6,000,000ms load times to 79.1ms :D

Comment: @Holabola Note that this makes `parameters` mutable. If you want it stay as a constant, see my answer.

Comment: Quick question, as I'm new to actually interacting with this site. This is the answer I'll more than likely use, but your answer is a more accurate answer, as you've noted. What answer would I choose in this scenario?

Comment: @Holabola Typically you want to upvote every answer that's useful/accurate, and accept whichever one you think is "best."  How you determine that is entirely up to you, nobody's going to complain unless you accept something that's seriously flawed.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a long time to build because there is a *big* dictionary literal. You can try to create the dictionary by using the `dict[key] = value` syntax.

```
let parameters: Parameters = {
    var dict = Parameters()
    dict["credit_union"] = credit_union
    dict["activity"] = activity
    // the rest of the KVPs goes here
    return dict
}()
```